# Trouble with Groovy to print Changelist description

Tags: groovy, perforce, p4api.net, p4java

I want to print the Changelist description of each changelist for a Particular stream , but the description that i am getting as output is limited to certain set of characters

```
changelistList.each { IChangelistSummary cl ->
  println cl.getDescription() 
    }
```

This is giving a limited CL description instead of the Full description as i see in p4V

```
  printed by script is - "settings IL customization"
  But the actual description is "settings IL customization Fix_For_TDP XXXXX_Additional Services section expanded on both Provide and Change"
```

Can any one help? what is wrong here? I dont get any compile errors, the script executes fine, just that i dont get the full description printed i even tried to use println cl.getDescription().toString() but it doesnt help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use the `getChangelist()` method to get the changelist with the full description:  https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r17.2/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/server/delegator/IChangeDelegator.html

Comment: changelistList in the above is the output of server.getChangelist()

Comment: @DevOops please look very carefully at Sam's answer compared to yours. You do **not** want the `IChangelistSummary`, you want the `IChangelist`. In command-line terms, it's the difference between `p4 changes` and `p4 change -o`. The `IChangelistSummary`, which you get from `p4 changes`, only has the truncated description, you need the `IChangelist`, which you get from `p4 change -o`, to see the full description.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification  Sam and Bryan